# How to increase Algorithm's top space to page margin?

Tags: spacing, algorithms

I have an algorithm at the top of a page. How can I increase the space between the algorithm and page's top margin?

The code looks like:

```
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Some Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
...
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

A `\vspace` can do the work for figures, for example, the following code can increase the space between figure and the top margin:

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\vspace{10ex}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=7in]{...}
\caption{Some Figure}
\end{figure*}
```

How can I do the similar thing for an `algorithm` environment?

Answer (score 1):

The default `f`loat `s`tyle assigned to the `algorithm` float by [`algorithm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) is `ruled`. Under the `ruled` option, the caption is placed at the top of the float (all managed by the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float)). With this is mind, one can tap into `\fs@pre` and add the necessary space as

> `\@fs@pre`, [..] is inserted at the very beginning of the float, `\@fs@mid`, [..] comes between the float and the caption (or the caption and the float, if captions are put at the top), and `\@fs@post`, [..] finishes off the float.

Here is the default definition associated with the `ruled` `f`loat `s`tyle:

```
\newcommand\fs@ruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
```

We can create a new `spaceruled` `f`loat `s`tyle

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@spaceruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{\vspace{5\baselineskip}\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatother
```

that only inserts a `\vspace` before setting the regular `\hrule`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@spaceruled{\def\@fs@cfont{\bfseries}\let\@fs@capt\floatc@ruled
  \def\@fs@pre{\vspace{5\baselineskip}\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}%
  \def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}%
  \def\@fs@mid{\kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt}%
  \let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \caption{Some Algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State print ``Hello World''
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
Some text

\clearpage      % force a new page here, only for the example

\floatstyle{spaceruled}% Select new float style
\restylefloat{algorithm}% Apply spaceruled float style to algorithm
\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \caption{Some Other Algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State print ``Hello New World''
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
Some text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an empty figure with some `vspace` (but without a caption) before the algorithm (with caption and label), and connect them together in a `subfigures` environment (for which you also don't provide a caption).

In an unexpected turn of events, the float placement specifier (`[t]`) of the algorithm actually places the whole subfigures environment on the top of the page.

The `subfigures` environment is provided by the `subfloat` package, so you need to add `\usepackage{subfloat}` before `\begin{document}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Some Algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State print "Hello World"
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\clearpage      % force a new page here, only for the example
Some more text which references Algorithm~\ref{alg:b}
\begin{subfigures}
\begin{figure}
\vspace{1cm}
\end{figure}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{Some Other Algorithm}
\label{alg:b}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State print "Hello New World"
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{subfigures}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]